# Problems sign XML with java 8u121 in windows

Tags: java, xml-dsig

I have signed a XML document with java 8 without problems, until I upgrade to the **Java 8u121** version, the code is:

```
    String xml_entrada = "D:\\CeslySoft\\Ivap_facturador\\CPE\\FirmaXML\\Schema-20480510144-RC-20170327-0001.xml";
    String xml_salida  = "D:\\CeslySoft\\Ivap_facturador\\CPE\\FirmaXML\\20480510144-RC-20170327-0001.xml";
    String certi_digital = "D:\\CeslySoft\\Ivap_facturador\\Certificados\\molchiclayo1.jks";        
    String clave = "9ghi0nmbR0ft";
    String alias = "1"; 
    String tipodoc = "09";      

    int indice = (tipodoc.equals("09")? 0: 1);      
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    Reference ref = fac.newReference("", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1,null),
            Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
            null,null);     
    SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, 
            (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), 
            fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(ref));

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(certi_digital), clave.toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry 
        = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(clave.toCharArray()));

    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
    List<Object> x509content = new ArrayList<>();
    x509content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    x509content.add(cert);      
    X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509content);
    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);        
    //Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(xml_entrada));
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xml_entrada), "ISO-8859-1"));
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);

    Node nodePadre = doc.getElementsByTagName("ext:ExtensionContent").item(indice);     
    nodePadre.getNodeValue();
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), nodePadre);

    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki, null, "SignatureSP", null);
    signature.sign(dsc);

    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(xml_salida);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");

    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
```

The error is in the line of code:

```
   signature.sign(dsc)
```

The error is:

```
javax.xml.crypto.XMLSignatureException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key
```

......

With versions prior to Java 8u121, do not occur nothing errors.

Comment: I think you are missing http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Comment: I have installed on many machines with java versions from 8u112, 8u111 .. 8u101 and do not needed any extension to execute fine. The problem is with the last version of java 8u121,  I had to uninstall the latest version and install any of the previous versions so that it does not produce any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug caused due to the fix made in JDK 8u121 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u121-relnotes-3315208.html ) "More checks added to DER encoding parsing code More checks are added to the DER encoding parsing code to catch various encoding errors. In addition, signatures which contain constructed indefinite length encoding will now lead to IOException during parsing. Note that signatures generated using JDK default providers are not affected by this change. 
JDK-8168714 (not public) "

This has been fixed already with JDK-8175251(https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175251 ) , which will be available in the next JDK update. The fix is already there in JDK 8u152, the early access version of which can be downloaded from https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: Thansk. Suspected that it was a bug in the JDK 8u121 which caused the problem, thanks for confirming it.